# How do you make the resolution bigger on a Canon Rebel T5i?

Tags: canon, resolution

All of my pictures come out super blurry if they are anything bigger that 5x7 and I want to fix it. So how do I change the resolution? Is it something I have to do BEFORE I take the pictures or am I able to do it after? I need help! Thank you!

Comment: Can you perhaps post (a link to a) a sample picture that you tried printing at 5x7? That would be helpful in determining the cause of the blurriness.

Comment: What resolution are the photos you are currently printing? Lack of resolution is only one among many things that can cause a larger print to be blurry.

Comment: Posting an example image would be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Several possibilities :

- back/front focus, easy to check : the sharp zone exists but isn't where you want
- low end lenses can make blur pictures. I mean even with good focus the pictures aren't really sharp, because of the quality of the lens.

In the first case, try to manually focus. And there are possibilities to tune it in the body.

In the second case, try to shoot at low aperture. The best picture sharpness is at f/9 for most lenses.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about prints?

Basically you can't *enlarge* the image dimensions afterwards without experiencing significant loss of quality. Consult your camera manual to locate the settings in the camera itself that allow you to define the size and format of images to take. Also, the amount of megapixels in your camera is directly related to the maximum dimensions of prints that can be made from its photos without losing crispness.